# Xcode 7 navigationcontrller issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode7

I am facing some kind of issue in my when I compile my code with xcode 7.

Here is my code:

```
 UIViewController *vcSomeObj = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vcSOmeClass"];
vcSomeObj.channelID   = detailOfUserTable.ID;
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[vcSomeObj] animated:NO];
```

This is working fine when I compile and run my code from xcode6.4.

This thing hang my application. And when I goes to any app and come agian to my app it will take to main controller and after sometime app crashes.

I can't find anything in debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In storyboard file We need to select English check box also otherwise application will hang an crash.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion.you set the current navigation's viewcontroller.what's happen to current viewController in navigation stack when you in current viewController,so ,I guess you can do like this

```
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[vcSomeObj,self] animated:NO];
```

Comment: Thank you for answer...but this is not issue. I figured out. In some project we need to check english in localozation.